# i m getting no such table: customer_customer error

Tags: python, django, forms, sqlite

Basically I want to accept the values from the form i.e customer form and save the values in the database. i m using django 1.9 and python 3.5.4. I can see my html form but when I enter values and submit I shows above error,also when I go to admin page and click on customer it again shows above error.  I am new to python n Django.

this is views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import CustomerForm
from .models import Customer
#from django.http return HttpResponse


def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = CustomerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
             cid = request.POST.get('cid','')
             name = request.POST.get('name','')
             age = request.POST.get('age','')
             dob = request.POST.get('dob','')
             income = request.POST.get('income','')
             address = request.POST.get('address','')
             city = request.POST.get('city','')
             pincode = request.POST.get('pincode','')
             c_obj = Customer(cid=cid, name=name, age=age, dob=dob,
                        income=income, address=address, city=city, pincode=pincode)
             c_obj.save()

             return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('customer/customer.html '))

    else:
            form = CustomerForm()


    return render(request,'customer/customer.html',{"form":form})
```

this is models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm



class Customer(models.Model):
    cid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    dob = models.DateField()
    income = models.IntegerField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    pincode = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cid


#class CustomerForm(ModelForm):
    #class Meta:
        #model = Customer
        #fields = ['cid','name','age','dob','income','address','city','pincode']
```

this is forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Customer


class CustomerForm(forms.Form):

     cid = forms.IntegerField()
     name = forms.CharField(max_length=140)
     age = forms.IntegerField()
     dob = forms.DateField()
     income = forms.IntegerField()
     address = forms.CharField(max_length=140)
     city = forms.CharField(max_length=140)
     pincode = forms.IntegerField()


     def clean_cid(self):
            cid = self.cleaned_data.get('cid')
            return cid

     def clean_name(self):
            name = self.cleaned_data.get('name')
            return name

     def clean_age(self):
            age = self.cleaned_data.get('age')
            return age

     def clean_dob(self):
            dob = self.cleaned_data.get('dob')
            return dob

     def clean_income(self):
            income = self.cleaned_data.get('income')
            return income

     def clean_address(self):
            address = self.cleaned_data.get('address')
            return address

     def clean_city(self):
            city = self.cleaned_data.get('city')
            return city

     def clean_pincode(self):
            pincode = self.cleaned_data.get('pincode')
            return pincode
```

solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: did you run `python manage.py makemigrations` followed by `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Additionally, once you get your model and database sorted out, you might want to [let Django build your form for you based on your model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/). It's much easier, and you get better guarantees that your form matches your model.

Comment: I did migrations but then too it shows same error @v1k45

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'customer',
]         DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'db.sqlite3'),
    }
} this is some part of my settings.py file, I have already included customer in installed apps then too error remains. do I need to do any changes in database section? I m using default database @Chris

Comment: is there any changes I need to do in my code?

Answer (score -1):

also youv have to include current module to settings file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'suit',  # django-suit
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.humanize',

'simple_history',
'localflavor',
'displays',
'products',)
```

**products** - it's my custom module with models and etc. after it was invluded do migrations like wrote above.

Comment: The OP says that the form is rendering and the `Customer` model appears in the admin, which means the relevant app is already included in `INSTALLED_APPS`.